# Confusing to my condition if else using two conditions

Tags: vb.net

How Can I use "AND" in if else condition.

1st Condition: `(Val(TextBox9.Text) > Val(time.Text))`

2nd Condition:

```
((Format(CDate(Strings.Right(TextBox9.Text.Trim, 11)))) > 
        (Format(CDate(Strings.Right(time.Text.Trim, 11)))))
```

I have a problem in my statement condition, it is always execute when the first condition becomes true. I want my condition execute when my two condition becomes true, My big problem is when my 1st condition becomes true and my second condition is false it still executing which is wrong, the output should be "Second Condition is false".

```
If (Val(TextBox9.Text) > Val(time.Text)) AndAlso 
           ((Format(CDate(Strings.Right(TextBox9.Text.Trim, 11)))) >
           (Format(CDate(Strings.Right(time.Text.Trim, 11))))) Then

     Console.writeline("Execute both condition is true")

else
     Console.writeline("Second Condition is false")


end if
```

Comment: the console message is wrong - the else will execute if EITHER condition is false.  The AndAlso just means the second test will not be performed if the first fails.  As for date tests, why not create some proper date variables and perform proper date tests on them?

Comment: yeah, but my project is already buildup and im having this one last problem, I want to have both of those condition will be read, so you are saying that I will use "And" rather than "AndAlso" I already tried it but still the first condition only is read.

Comment: just deny my console message it just an example, All I want is to read my both conditions

Comment: it will test for both conditions as is, the likely problem is that muddled mess chopping up text input to date values.  Set a breakpoint and use the immediate window to see if they are being parsed into anything close to what you expect.  .NET has wonderful conversion methods and far superior to `Val` which should burned and banished.  In the first case, you convert `time` (a textbox???) to a Double, for the second case you convert part of it to a Date.  Create a couple of temp variables for the test.  (turn on `Option Strict` to see how many problems you **really** have)

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble diagnosing the issue with your conditionals, break them up into several lines, to help you better understand what you are comparing.  For example you could do this:

```
Dim firstCompare = Val(TextBox9.Text) > Val(Time.Text)

Dim formattedTB9 = Format(CDate(Strings.Right(TextBox9.Text.Trim, 11)))
Dim formattedTime = Format(CDate(Strings.Right(Time.Text.Trim, 11)))

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} > {1}", formattedTB9, formattedTime))

Dim secondCompare = formattedTB9 > formattedTime

If (firstCompare) AndAlso (secondCompare) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Execute both condition is true")
Else
    Console.WriteLine("One of the conditions is false")
End If
```

Now looking at your code, are you sure you want to be comparing formatted strings of dates and times you just converted from a textbox?  Now that things are broken up, leverage the debugger to determine what values you are comparing and focus on tweaking it to be exactly what you want.  Use the correct datatypes when comparing objects and ensure you understand how functions like `Val` and `CDate` work.

Comment: Copy and paste isn't going to solve this problem.  You need to set breakpoints and interpret the data.  Only you know what your program should be doing.  What I have posted is a method to help you figure that out.

Comment: Could You help me how can I do this comparing please, im just a beginner for this project this is my first job, My project is done nad this my last problem, my client concern.

Comment: This is the sample data that I am comparing 08.25 06/10/2014  And 23.18 06/09/2014 The first two is the Hours and mins this is a military time and the last is the date format month day year.

Comment: Could you suggest me how can I compare that based on Date and Time so that I will not used "And".

Answer (score -1):

This is not a good way to compare two dates and times. You should first compare dates (not dates converted to strings) and only if they are same compare times. That's because if one date is larger or smaller than other, time doesn't matter. But when they are same, time is important. And you shouldn't compare strings, because when it's formated mm/dd/yyyy, months and days are more important for comparing than years.

```
If CDate(Strings.Right(TextBox9.Text.Trim, 11))>CDate(Strings.Right(time.Text.Trim, 11)) Then
     Console.writeline("Date1 is bigger")
elseif CDate(Strings.Right(TextBox9.Text.Trim, 11))=CDate(Strings.Right(time.Text.Trim, 11))
     If Val(TextBox9.Text) > Val(Time.Text) Then
          Console.writeline("Date1 is bigger")
     elseif Val(TextBox9.Text) = Val(Time.Text)
          Console.writeline("Dates are equal")
     else
          Console.writeline("Date1 is smaller")
     end if
else
Console.writeline("Date1 is smaller")
end if
```